# Save a reference to this within jQuery's $('selector').each()

Tags: jquery

I'm storing information about links in an array. I want to be able to reference the links later through jQuery. How do I save the reference to each link as part of the information associated with the element? When I define `reference: $(this)`, then `reference` always refers to the very last link in the for loop for *every* link (i.e. some type of problem with references).

```
var linkInfo = new Array();

$("a").each(function(index, elt)  {
    var currentInfo = {};

    currentInfo.i = index;

    // Gather info about the <a> tag
    currentInfo.link = {
        reference: $(this), // todo fix this reference: info.link.reference yields last object
        offset: $(this).offset(), 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like:

```
$("a").each(function(index, elt)  {
    var currentInfo = {};
    var $that = $(this);
    currentInfo.i = index;

    // Gather info about the <a> tag
    currentInfo.link = {
        reference: $that, // todo fix this reference: info.link.reference yields last object
        offset: $(this).offset()
    }
}
```